# How do I reference the package version in chocolateyinstall.ps1?

Tags: chocolatey

I am packaging an existing installer with Chocolatey. The installer has the format `<appname>-<version>.exe` where version is, for example, 1.0.0. I am using `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage`, but I don't know how to reference the installer. I am using `$version$` in the nuspec to include the file in the package.

Is there a way to get the version in the install/uninstall script, or do I have to do something like `gci .\Application-*.exe` to get the full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the installer version matches the nuspec `<version />`, you can use the `ChocolateyPackageVersion` environment variable. See https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-reference#variables for the full list.

### Package Creation Recommendations

#### FOSS

It's best if you use `choco new pkgid` when creating packages. It is going to set everything up for you and save you quite a bit of time as it brings quite a bit of what we call "just in time" documentation. Some parts of your question are answered already when you run `choco new`, plus it sets you up for success. For instance, your next question will be "Why can't I use `.\Application-*.exe` in the package scripts?" We recommend you use `$toolsDir\Application-*.exe`, and when you run `choco new`, you will see what `$toolsDir` is set to (for clarity, you will need to have the `$toolsDir` variable created locally and set in the package script).

#### Pro - Package Builder UI

Chocolatey Pro (for individuals) has Package Builder UI (minus auto-detection), that can allow you to have a nice interface to use in package creation. It will give you all of the elements of `choco new pkgid`, but also quite a bit more out of the gate.

#### Business - Package Builder (w/auto-detection)

Chocolatey for Business (C4B) comes with Package Builder (both CLI with `choco new --file installer.exe` and Package Builder UI). Package Builder does auto-detection on the actual installer (MSI, EXE, 7Z, ZIP, MSP, MSU) to generate a fully ready to go unattended deployment (package) in about 5-10 seconds. It supports right click and create package.

https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-create-packages-from-installers